# Currying function which retains value using closure

Tags: javascript, closures, currying

I was asked in an interview to write a currying function which retains value using closure(Javascript).
Example:
`add(1, 2, 3)(4)(5, 6);`
`add(7, 8);`
`add(9)(10);`
`add();`
Output of above line of code should be 55 after execution of last **add** function.

So it should be like-
`add(1, 2, 3)(4)(5, 6); -> 21`
`add(7, 8); -> 21(previous value) + 15 -> 36`
`add(9)(10); -> 36(previous value) + 19 -> 55`
`add(); -> 55(final output)`

could someone please me with the solution? Thanks in advance.

I tried the below approach but not able to retain the value as on every call **finalOutput** variable gets reinitialised to 0. I tried wrapping it in another function to leverage the closure feature but didn't work.

```
function add(...arg) {
    let finalOutput = 0;
    if (arg.length === 0) {
        return finalOutput;
    }
    return function (...newArg) {
        if (newArg.length) {
        let argsArr = [...arg, ...newArg];
        finalOutput = argsArr.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
            return acc + currentValue;
        });
        return add(finalOutput);
        } else {
          return finalOutput;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: The tasks asks for a global variable, which is a bad idea. Your approach is much better.

Comment: i tried it, but because of nested calls, call stack size exceeds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper function (`createAdder`, for example) that wraps your code which stores the total sum. That wrapper function will return your `add` function which you can store in a variable (`add`) and then use to get your total output, for example:

```js
function createAdder() {
  let finalOutput = 0;
  return function add(...args) {
    if(args.length === 0)
      return finalOutput;
    
    finalOutput += args.reduce((sum, v) => sum + v, 0);
    return add;
  }
}


const add = createAdder();

add(1, 2, 3)(4)(5, 6);
add(7, 8);
add(9)(10);
console.log(add());
```

Comment: why just not use IIFE to create private scope

Comment: @AfzalK. That would work as well. I guess this way you have the opportunity to create multiple adder "instances" if desired, each independently keeping their own count.

Answer (score 0):

we can do it by checking if there are any arguments passed to the function. If not, then return the total value, so this way we can call the `add()` without any arguments and get the accumulated value.

```js
function add(...args) {
  if(!add.total) add.total = 0;
  
  if(!args || args.length === 0) {
    let total = add.total;
    add.total = undefined; // reset once retrieved
    return total;
  }
  
  add.total += args.reduce((sum, v) => sum + v, 0);
  return add;
}

add(1, 2, 3)(4)(5, 6);
add(7, 8);
add(9)(10);
console.log(add());

add(9)(10);
console.log(add());
```

Comment: Better simply declare `let total = 0` outside of the function, instead of storing it as an optional property on the function object.

Comment: @Bergi didnt OP wanted it that way?

Comment: modified it a bit, so once accessed it resets the total, and starts again

Comment: OP asked for a closure, they did not ask for a function property

Comment: obviously......